# Multiplication of two exponential functions with dot product

Tags: vectors, exponential-function

I need to find multiplication of two exponential contain vectors as below,
$$e^{i\textbf{p}.\textbf{R}_{A}}e^{-i\textbf{p}.\textbf{R}_{B}}$$ here $\textbf{p},\textbf{R}_{A},\textbf{R}_{B}$ are vectors, therefore $\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{R}_{A},\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{R}_{B}$ denote dot product. Moreover, $$\textbf{R}=\textbf{R}_{A}-\textbf{R}_{B}$$

I need to show $$e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot \textbf{R}_{A}}e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{R}_{B}}=e^{i\textbf{p}.\textbf{R}}$$
I first thought this is too simple and tried like this, 
$$e^{i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{R}_{A}}e^{-i\textbf{p}\cdot\textbf{R}_{B}}=e^{ipR_{A}\cos(\theta_{A})}.e^{-ipR_{B}\cos(\theta_{B})}$$
$$e^{ipR_{A}\cos(\theta_{A})}.e^{-ipR_{B}\cos(\theta_{B})}=e^{ip(R_{A}\cos(\theta_{A})-R_{B}\cos(\theta_{B}))}$$

But, I am stuck here. In order to prove this I need to take that $R_{A}\cos(\theta_{A})-R_{B}\cos(\theta_{B})=R\cos(\theta)$, where $\cos(\theta)$ is the angle between $\textbf{p}$ and $\textbf{R}$. But I don't know how to continue after that.

Comment: From what you've written, It seems you mean the dot product, not the cross product.

Comment: @Sten  thanks alot for pointing out my mistake. now i corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is trivial and doesn't need any kind of decomposition with angles. $i(p\cdot R_A)$ is a complex number, so the usual rules for exponentiation hold. Also note that the dot product is linear in the second argument:

$$e^{i(p\cdot R_A)} e^{-i(p\cdot R_B)} = e^{i(p \cdot R_A - p \cdot R_B)} = e^{i(p\cdot(R_A - R_B))} = e^{i(p\cdot R)}$$

Comment: thanks heaps. My issue is with taking $e^{i(p\cdot R_A)} e^{-i(p\cdot R_B)} = e^{i(p \cdot R_A - p \cdot R_B)} $. I don't know how this is possible when we consider with angles and all? any little help on taking this step?

Comment: This is just an application of the equality $e^ae^b = e^{a + b}$ that holds for all complex numbers $a, b$.

Comment: But how can we do this for dot products? My confusion is in that case

Comment: The dot product of two complex vectors is a **complex number**.

Comment: Thanks How is it possible to decompose dot product in to $e^{i(p\cdot R_A)} e^{-i(p\cdot R_B)}= e^{i(p\cdot(R_A - R_B))}$, this is where I don't understand

Comment: I really have no idea how to break this down even more.

Comment: How did you directly take out the vector $p$ from the bracket and isolate $R_{A}-R_{B}$ part. This is what I dont understand. i believe this can be proved with angles between vectors

Comment: Because the dot product is linear in both arguments. If $a, b, c$ are vectors, then a direct computation shows $a\cdot b + a \cdot c = a \cdot(b + c)$.

Comment: Thanks alot. I tried to prove this identity. Now got it